# Use many-to-many related field count to sort list view

Tags: django, django-admin

I managed to get the count of my related many-to-many field into the list view but I'm failing to use it to sort the list.

```
class GuestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (GuestEpisodeAdmin, TopicGuestAdmin, JobGuestAdmin)
    exclude = ('episodes', )
    list_display = ('name', 'twitter', 'gender', 'medium', 'episode_count')

    def episode_count(self, obj):
        return obj.episodes.all().count()
```

I have seen similar stuff being done with custom querysets but I don't have a clue how to get my count into that. I'm not even sure if the way I do the count is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After some more trying I found it out myself.

using `get_queryset` method I was able to annotate the episode count

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(GuestAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    return qs.annotate(episode_count=Count('episodes'))
```

and then use it for sorting

```
appearance_count.admin_order_field = 'episode_count'
```